# How can I modify font-family styling in an external SVG file fetched from a CDN link in .NET Maui Blazor Hybrid?

Tags: asp.net, .net, svg, blazor, maui

How can I modify a CSS `font-family` applied to an `img` tag in from an external SVG file CDN resource in .NET Maui Blazor Hybrid?

[image: .NET Maui Blazor Hybrid Image Display]

I previously tried to modify the `<img src="..." />` tag to properly utilize the updated `font-family` for the font after the source has been fetched. The `src=` attribute successfully retrieves the back-end CDN link which holds the SVG file.

The problem is once the SVG file has been loaded and displayed in the Razor Markup when running the application, it does not apply any font styling updates to the markup's `img` tag. I believe the SVG file being stored and fetched from another resource dynamically is preventing modifications to the stylization. I also wonder if I cannot modify the `font-family` loaded in the `img` tag due to .NET Maui Blazor limitations with this external resource.

Razor Code-

`<img src="@IconURL" width="150" height="150" />`

Where `IconURL` is a `string` property that contains the CDN link which holds the SVG file. In my dev tools screenshot, it displays the `img` tag styling needed but does not display the actual font.

You can see the `<img />` tag displayed in the .NET Maui Blazor Hybrid Dev Tools Window.
This displays the image properly but allows for no changes to be made after initialization and first load to the font within the SVG.

Does .NET Maui Blazor Hybrid not allow for modifying an image's font after the Razor component loads?
I need to modify the actual SVG content styling itself but that is stored in the SVG file from the CDN link. What are some possible solutions or options to achieve the result?

Comment: You should also **check the svg file (search for `<text>` tags)**. Quite often logos use hardcoded `<path>` elements (so, text was converted to paths to avoid font embedding issues). In this case you won't be able to change the font. Your screenshot actually indicates this: An **embedded font would have a larger filesize**. To make things worse: your logo svg might contain an embedded png image – so you could not style anything.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I looked into the SVG element from the source with the devtools. It does have a `<text>` element for the text shown. I will attempt the solution provided as it maybe the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that MAUI Blazor is preventing you from modifying your font style.

According to SVG's documentation [The quick way: img element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web#the_quick_way_img_element), when you use the img tag to display an SVG image, you cannot modify its style externally.

> If you want to control the SVG content with CSS, you must include inline CSS styles in your SVG code. (External stylesheets invoked from the SVG file take no effect.)

After the following tests, when referencing an SVG file via a url link, its style cannot be modified.

```
// In this test, I only modified the URL of data to network and local for testing.
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="test.svg"></object>
```

```
// Use the following code to get the SVG object in the Object tag and modify the font of all Text tags in SVG.
function ChangeFont() {
            const objTag = document.querySelector('object');
            const svg = objTag.getSVGDocument();
            Array.from(svg.getElementsByTagName('text'))
                .forEach(p => p.setAttribute('font-family', 'monospace'));
        }
```

When the referenced SVG is local, all text can be successfully modified to `monospace`. However, when referencing URL links, `objTag.getSVGDocument();` will return null.

Update:

You could refer to the following steps to call this Javascript method in a razor page.

Step 1. Add the above js method `ChangeFont` into `wwwroot/index.html`.

Step 2. Call this method in a `razor` page using C# code:

```
@code{
    private async Task SVGChangeFont()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("ChangeFont");
    }
}
```

Step 3. Set this method to the load event of .

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="helloworld.svg" @onload="SVGChangeFont"></object>
```

Comment: If the URL is the same domain as the calling document it will work. Also if the remote domain has configured CORS to permit it.

Comment: I appreciate the information from all of you. The source domain of the application is not matching the base URL of the document. I think the answer provided is the most clarifying approach. Although that is very helpful information going forward.

Comment: @ALEC - MSFT I appreciate your response. It looks like your code is JavaScript, I assume we would have to use `IJSRuntime` in Razor and call the JavaScript function. There is no Blazor or C# approach currently I take it. If there is, please let me know.

Comment: I've updated my answer about how to invoke this JavaScript function in razor page. Could you please check it?